# What does the Kinetic Strike Module do?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown, xcom-enemy-within

According to the description, the Kinetic Strike Module lets Mecs punch stuff and increases mobility. What exactly are the effects? Is the number of uses limited in some way? How much damage does it deal? Do I need to be adjacent to an enemy to use it? How much is mobility improved?

Comment: 12 damage, point blank use, small enemies are hurled backwards and can do damage and blow up cars - saw all that in prerelease videos. No real data, though, waiting for a Steam sale, sorry :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Usage, Damage & Effects

The Kinetic Strike does 12 guaranteed damage to an adjacent unit. This can be upgraded to 18 by a Foundry project. Note that only the 4 squares that share sides with the MEC's square are considered adjacent - *not* diagonal squares. If an enemy is in an adjacent square but the other side of a wall, the attack will punch through the wall to hit them, destroying the wall in the process.

Enemies fly backwards a substantial distance from the force of the punch if they die, and they destroy any cover that they hit. If the target is thrown into another enemy, this does not hurt the second enemy. However, it can destroy their cover, and if the target hits a car or other explosive then they will set it off.

If Kinetic Strike is used to kill a Mechtoid or a Muton Beserker, instead of the usual animation we see our MEC grapple with the enemy briefly, and the enemy may not be thrown backwards. This can cause damage to objects to the side of the target.

Kinetic Strike can also be free-aimed in any of the four grid-aligned directions. This may be useful for destroying cover, or for attacking an enemy that the player knows about but does not have line of sight to. Additionally, a free-aimed punch can destroy the power conduits in the final Slingshot mission (pointless but fun :-)).

### Implementation & movement increase

Kinetic Strike has an unlimited number of uses, and no cooldown. It can be used when the main weapon has no ammunition.
If the damage increase foundry project has been completed, MECs can use Kinetic Strike twice in one turn instead of moving.

The module appears to increase the distance that a MEC can move on a single action point by 3 squares. Specifically, a level 1 flamethrower-equipped MEC can move 7 squares on its first action, and a level 1 kinetic strike equipped MEC can move 10 squares. This movement increase may sometimes be a more important effect than the punch itself...

Comment: My MEC does 18 damage with a single punch. Also, I found that the punch can be done twice per turn after you get the trooper skill that lets you fire on first half-turn without ending the turn.

Comment: Sectopods do get thrown back on a fatal Kinetic Strike.  I lost a meld canister that way.

Comment: @Kexlox thanks. I've edited to remove the query on that.

Comment: @kotekzot Thanks. Do you know the name of that skill? If so, please feel free to edit it in. Otherwise I'll update when my MEC levels up :-)

Comment: I hit a berserker and didn't kill it, It didn't fly back. Then it did the intimidate thing and moved on its own.

Comment: Overdrive is the name of the Major skill that allows you to fire a primary weapon on your first action and no longer end the turn.

Comment: Hitting an enemy and flying it into another enemy will not hurt the second enemy, but it can and will destroy its cover.

Comment: It will cause the cover to explode if it is a car though, which can kill the unit behind it.  Also there is a foundry project that upgrades the damage from 12 to 18.  18 damage is huge, and very hand when you have three sectopods staring down your team.